# Unable to find why a particular code line is showing error

Tags: java, object, reference

```
package morepackage;

public class Exampleclass {

String s = "myname";

public static void main( )

{

    Object [] a = new Object[10];

    a[1] = new Exampleclass();

    System.out.println( a[1] );//this is working

    System.out.println( a[1].s);//**this is not working**

    Exampleclass t = new Exampleclass();

    System.out.println(t);//this is working

    System.out.println(t.s);//this is working
}

}
```

Some of the above lines in the code are working and others are not can anyone please

explain why the line ***"System.out.println( a[1].s);"*** is showing error.

Comment: You need to cast a to Exampleclass

Comment: `a[1]` is an `Object` instance, and `Object` has no field named `s`. You need to cast as commented above by MihaiC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
System.out.println( a[1].s);
```

with

```
System.out.println( ((Exampleclass)a[1]).s);
```

`a` is an array of `Objects`, so you need to cast it's elements to `Exampleclass` before you can use any methods or properties defined in `Exampleclass`.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `System.out.println(t.s);`, property `s` of `t`, which is of type `Exampleclass` is being accessed and printed. But `a[1]`, which is an `Object`, has no such property.

Comment: Question is: **why** a particular code line is showing error, not how to concatenate.

Comment: a[1] is not a string, it's an Object

Comment: yes but still it's not the question being asked. OP wants to know why his code doesn't work, and it's because he is trying to use a property or method of Exampleclass on a Object. It's not a concatenation problem

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with me today. Apologies. Again updated.

Answer (score 0):

```java
package morepackage;

public class Exampleclass 
{

  String s = "myname";

  public static void main( )

  {

    // array of objects
    Object [] a = new Object[10];

    a[1] = new Exampleclass();

    // prints an object not an instance Exampleclass class
    System.out.println( a[1] );//this is working

    // System.out.println( a[1].s);//**this is not working**

    Exampleclass temp = (Exampleclass) a[1];

    System.out.println( temp.s)


    Exampleclass t = new Exampleclass();

    System.out.println(t);//this is working

    System.out.println(t.s);//this is working
  }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to cast a[1] aiming to access s property like

```
System.out.println( ((Exampleclass)a[1]).s);
```

Comment: You don't explain why OP code is not working, which is the question being asked :)